# Offer a bounty and add details to a question

Tags: discussion

I have been stuck in a problem for more than 2 days. There is already a similar question, in which the user though intended to know the answer a little bit differently, but that is only evident from comments to Q & A.

There isn't an accepted answer, though the question is about 4 years old.

I do not want to ask a new question. I did rather want to add how I have tried to solve the problem, with already available answers and its still not working. I would offer a bounty but not without adding my details. Also its hard for me to currently say that my own question won't be marked as a duplicate.

The post of my concern is: [Upload a file to server automatically inside a update panel in asp.net website](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8310832/365188)

How can I address this problem?

Comment: Best way to get a response would probably be to ask a new question with full details of the problem, linking to the old one, and stating explicitly why the old one did not resolve your problem. Perhaps not ideal, although any attempt to get a new answer to a similar question (with a different tact required) just by adding a bounty to the original question would likely result in simply people restating what has already been provided. I think it would be better to start with a clean slate.

Comment: What makes yours different to the other one? Maybe the answers solve your problem but there's a change that needs to be done.

Comment: I have tried the changes, that is why I need to add details to the question.

Comment: You *could* leave a comment on the answer if you need clarification on something. Then if you get one, you could offer a bounty and award it to that answer. However, since it's 4 years old, I wouldn't hold out much hope. You are probably better off doing what Grade said. I'm guessing that your changes to the question will change too much that you don't know if it's relevant to the original post

Comment: @codeMagic Yeah! Already did that a day ago. Now, I have [asked another question:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34227505/uploading-a-file-to-server-automatically-inside-an-update-panel-does-not-work-th) and realized while wirting my question that it indeed does differ :)

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon - You should make your comment the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To flesh out my comment a little further, it is recommended that you ask a new question rather than attempt to reconfigure an old one to suit your needs.

Firstly, this prevents loss of information which may not be applicable to you, but was applicable to the original asker.

Secondly, this increases the focus of responses onto your particular issues, whereas otherwise some responses would be geared partly towards your problem and partly towards the original problem.

To get the best results from re-asking a similar question, you should **fully state your question**, including all relevant details, so that an answer could be provided without any outside reading. Then, **link to the old question, explicitly stating why the old question is insufficient for your purposes**. This will allow answers to be more specific to your new issue - it will also help to create a chain back to the other, similar problem, which may help searchers who find your question but need the original solution.

Finally, you can **link to your new question from the old one in a comment on the 'almost' answer, tagging that user.** This may help you get attention from the user(s) which originally answered the question, although if your particular case is 4 years old, that is maybe unlikely.

Answer (score -1):

Just be aware the people may not read your question and mark it as a duplicate -- and as far as I can tell that flag is permanent.