# Thread marked as duplicate: what could I have done differently?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I started [one thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312285/better-to-reduplicate-or-to-edit-a-poorly-worded-question-with-no-good-answers) at meta asking what to do if a previous question wasn't great/wasn't answered: should I start a new thread even it is a duplicate? This thread was closed as a duplicate, with the answer at [the original](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312172/offer-a-bounty-and-add-details-to-a-question) being "Start a new thread":

> To get the best results from re-asking a similar question, you should
>   fully state your question, including all relevant details, so that an
>   answer could be provided without any outside reading. Then, link to
>   the old question, explicitly stating why the old question is
>   insufficient for your purposes. This will allow answers to be more
>   specific to your new issue - it will also help to create a chain back
>   to the other, similar problem, which may help searchers who find your
>   question but need the original solution.

So, after explicitly asking what to do, and getting that, I indeed [started a new thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312498/feature-request-add-a-link-within-a-question-or-answer), being sure to cite the previous question when it was asked, giving a detailed account of how the previous questions/answers were not sufficient for my purposes. This new thread was immediately closed as a duplicate.

This seems to contradict the answer at the initial thread. What should I have done differently?

Comment: The fact that a [feature-request] does not have a post marked as the answer is in itself not a good reason to just repeat the feature request.  Ideally all [feature-request] questions get resolved by SE staff to, say, [status-declined] and you'd know there is no point in continuing to ask for it.  Sadly this does not happen nearly enough, "no" is not a popular outcome I guess.  @Michael's answer is excellent with solid reasoning, that it is not popular either does not make it a bad answer.

Comment: @HansPassant so perhaps I should have posed it as discussion instead?

Comment: Hmm, no, no amount of discussion is going to make an SE programmer implement this feature.  It was requested before and ignored, you can't always get what you want.  You tried.

Comment: @HansPassant that's pretty much all I was after, probably would have been the right answer at my initial question which was closed as a dupe. This has been a lot of time crapped down the sink that's for sure. Sheesh.